# View changes to a particular Windows API header file across builds?

Tags: windows, winapi, header-files, uxtheme, msstyles

`vsstyle.h` and `vssym32.h` are the sources of truth for some theme-related information on Windows. Specifically, they include IDs of [states and parts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/parts-and-states) of Win32 controls, which can be themed via`.msstyles` files.

These header files are packaged with Visual Studio and can be found at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\{BUILD}\um\{HEADER_FILE}.h`.

Is there any way to see the differences in these header files across Windows builds or across Visual Studio versions?

The use case is for building an editor for `.msstyles` files. If the IDs of states and parts are known across Windows builds, then it'd be possible to attempt migrating a Windows 7 theme to Windows 10/11 programmatically.

Comment: Doesn't Windows need .msstyles files to be signed for it to recognise them?

Comment: @JonathanPotter Yes, but there are ways around that (eg. [SecureUxTheme](https://github.com/namazso/SecureUxTheme))

Comment: You can install all SDKs aside and compare files using comparison tool. I have 7 Windows SDKs versions, installed for that same kind of purpose.

Comment: @SimonMourier Ah interesting, that sounds pretty viable. How are you installing so many SDK versions? [I'm seeing just 5 with the "Desktop development with C++" installer](https://i.imgur.com/y7xVsgg.png)

Comment: Older Visual Studios come with older SDKs but Microsoft also keeps archives https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive/